# Find element by CSS Selector behaviour difference

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, syntax, css-selectors

This is the xml snippet [`div id=":6r" class="Ar Au" style="display: block;"`]

To locate an element by css selector, i tried by giving the div element followed by the class name with dot(.), but it did not work

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.Ar.Au").send_keys("ABC")
```

However the below worked,

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".Ar.Au div).send_keys("ABC")
```

Can someone please tell me why the 1st one did not work ?

Below is the error log using the 1st option:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
>   element not interactable

Comment: yes in css selector we have to use it like (.class1.class2.class3)

Comment: What issue are you facing when you used firstone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`div.Ar.Au`** mean locate the `<div>` which has these class name (`Ar`and`Au`) as an attribute. So in this case its gonna locate `<div id=":6r" class="Ar Au" style="display: block;">`

**`.Ar.Au div`** this mean locate the child `<div>` tag under a tag which has class name (`Ar`and `Au`). So this one is locating the child `<div>` under `<div id=":6r" class="Ar Au" style="display: block;">`

**Note**: dot(`.`) is used in CSS selector to represent a class name and select compound classes

Comment: Thank you Narendra. I have missed to notice that .Ar.Ar div was actually locating the child div under this main div. The class Ar Au is infact a non interact-able element and thats the reason the first query by div.Ar.Au was failing as expected.